# pipes in angular 2 for time 00:00:00z

Tags: angular, date, pipe, user-defined-types, gmt

I have a json format

```
{
endDate:"2017-05-15Z"
id:"9od718ztlx8dffe3f1q78bc1t"
name:"Clausura - Quarter-finals"
startDate:"2017-05-11Z"
**time:"01:00:00Z"**
}
```

I need convert the time to gmt. I try with various pipes but the result always is the same. Anyone know if I can turn the time with any pipe?
My error is this with any pipe

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./CalendarComponent class CalendarComponent - inline template:11:16 caused by: Invalid argument '01:00:00Z' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse your date in a `Date` object before passing it to `date` pipe.

As your date seem to be an ISO 8601, but a bit malformed (only date, no hour:min:sec), `Date.parse` should be able to handle it.

First of all, parse your string using `Date`:

`let dateObj = Date.parse(yourObject.time)`

and then, pass this date object to your template using date pipe:

`{{dateObj | date}}`

Comment: Hello
I think it's backwards, it only brings hours, minutes and seconds
Apparently date.parse if you have a date
The result with date.parse gives me NaN =(